# Angular Reactive Forms custom validator minimum and maximum checked checkboxes

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular Reactive Form where people select minimum 1 and maximum 3 fruits they like most.

Template:

```
<div>
    <h3>Which maximum 3 fruits do you like best?</h3>
    <form *ngIf="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)" novalidate>
        <div *ngFor="let answer of answers.controls; let i=index">
            <input type="checkbox" [formControl]="answer">{{fruits[i]}}<br>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Component:

```
export class AppComponent {

  myForm: FormGroup;
  fruits: Array<string> = ["apple", "pear", "kiwi", "banana", "grape", "strawberry", "grapefruit", "melon", "mango", "plum"];

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({}, {
      validator: this.anotherValidator.bind(this)
    });
    let answersFormArray = this.fruits.map(fruit => { return this.formBuilder.control(false, [this.validateMaxCheckboxes.bind(this)]) });
    this.myForm.setControl('answers', this.formBuilder.array(answersFormArray));
  }

  validateMaxCheckboxes(control: FormControl) {
    return null;
  };

  anotherValidator(group: FormGroup) {
    return null;
  };

  get answers(): FormArray {
    return this.myForm.get('answers') as FormArray;
  };

  onSubmit(submit) {
    console.log(submit.answers);
  }

}
```

Which maximum 3 fruits do you like best? Then a list of fruit is displayed (checkboxes) that the user can select.

I want to have this behaviour:

**If the user selects nothing, submit button is disabled, minimum 1 fruit needs to be selected. If the user has selected 1 or 2 fruits, submit button is enabled. If the user selects the 3rd fruit (3 check boxes are checked), I want to disable all the fruits not checked, submit button stays enabled. If one of the 3 fruits checked is unchecked then all checkboxes are enabled. This way the user can select minimum 1 and maximum 3 fruits from the list.**

I tried many things, googled a lot but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of @ArunKumaresh also works but was too far away from my original code. But he pointed me in the right direction, so I could come up with this solution:

Template:

```
<div>
    <h3>Which maximum 3 fruits do you like best</h3>
    <form *ngIf="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)" novalidate>
        <div *ngFor="let answer of answers.controls; let i=index">
            <input type="checkbox" [formControl]="answer" (change)="onChangeAnswer($event.target.checked)">{{fruits[i]}}<br>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Component:

```
export class AppComponent {

  fruits: Array<string> = ["apple", "pear", "kiwi", "banana", "grape", "strawberry", "grapefruit", "melon", "mango", "plum"];
  myForm: FormGroup;
  numChecked: number = 0;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({}, {
      validator: this.minOneAnswer.bind(this)
    });
    let answersFormArray = this.fruits.map(fruit => { return this.formBuilder.control(false) });
    this.myForm.setControl('answers', this.formBuilder.array(answersFormArray));
  }

  minOneAnswer(control) {
    return this.numChecked === 0 ? { minOneAnswerChecked: true } : null;
  }

  onChangeAnswer(checked: boolean) {
    checked ? this.numChecked++ : this.numChecked--;
    const answerFormArray = this.myForm.get('answers') as FormArray;
    if (this.numChecked >= 3) {
      answerFormArray.controls.forEach((item) => {
        if (!item.value) item.disable()
      })
    } else {
      answerFormArray.controls.forEach((item) => {
        if (!item.value) item.enable()
      })
    }
  }

  get answers(): FormArray {
    return this.myForm.get('answers') as FormArray;
  };

  onSubmit(form: FormGroup) {
    const answerFormArray = form.get('answers') as FormArray;
    answerFormArray.controls.forEach((item) => {
      if (!item.value) item.enable()
    })
    console.log(form.value);
  }
}
```